# android app error "failed to start several times. Restore it by clearing history?"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile-application, mobile-development

When I run the app on my phone I get this error:

[image]

It shows for most of the programs I try to run and I don't know why... I googled it but can't find a solution.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral40"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@color/material_dynamic_secondary95"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="5 + 5 = ........."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="32"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
        android:text="14"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Done"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is logcat output:

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22797) for package com.view.buttons ----------------------------
2023-09-22 19:38:23.590 22797-22797 AppCompatDelegate       com.view.buttons
    D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2023-09-22 19:38:23.652 22797-22797 om.view.button          com.view.buttons
    W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-09-22 19:38:23.653 22797-22797 om.view.button          com.view.buttons
    W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-09-22 19:38:23.664 22797-22797 AndroidRuntime          com.view.buttons
    D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-22 19:38:23.669 22797-22797 AndroidRuntime          com.view.buttons
    E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.view.buttons, PID: 22797
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.view.buttons/com.view.buttons.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.view.buttons:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.view.buttons:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.view.buttons:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.view.buttons:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.view.buttons:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:855)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1012)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at com.view.buttons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.view.buttons:color/material_dynamic_neutral40 with resource ID #0x7f0501a6
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.view.buttons:color/material_dynamic_neutral40" (7f0501a6) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0501a6 a=-1 r=0x7f0501a6}

2023-09-22 19:38:23.670 22797-22797 AndroidRuntime          com.view.buttons
    E   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:879)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:719)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:924)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1005)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:980)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5351)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:677)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:669)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:587)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:855)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1012)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at com.view.buttons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)

2023-09-22 19:38:23.684 22797-22797 Process                 com.view.buttons                     I  Sending signal. PID: 22797 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (22797) for package com.view.buttons ---------------------------
```

I googled it but found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the log, it seems it can not find the colour for: `android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral40`

Comment: I changed that drawable to white and still the same